# Shapely intersection error while polygons are valid

Tags: python, gis, shapely

I've been trying to find out if 2 polygons are intersected and calculate the percentage of intersected area. Unfortunately, i've got a strange error, saying

`UnsupportedOperationException: GeometryGraph::add(Geometry *): unknown geometry type: N4geos4geom7PolygonE
    raise err
shapely.errors.TopologicalError: This operation could not be performed. Reason: unknown`

I have no idea why I'm getting this cause my polygons are valid and I can count area and check the intersection

```
print(geom_p8[0].is_valid)
print(intersect_poly.is_valid)
print(intersect_poly.intersects(geom_p8[0]))
print(intersect_poly.intersection(geom_p8[0]))

True
True
True
```

The polygons are:

```
coords = [(18994.7, 25920.75), (18986.5, 25900), (18985.55, 25892.9), (19006.55, 25882.85), (19013.85, 25899.55), (18994.7, 25920.75)]
intersect_poly = Polygon(coords)
```

and(this one is from .mif file which i've imported using fiona)

```
POLYGON ((18994.7 25920.75, 18986.5 25905, 18985.55 25892.9, 19006.55 25882.85, 19013.85 25899.55, 18994.7 25920.75))
```

Could someone please explain how to solve this problem? Should I use any other package?

Comment: The polygons seem to be the same. Did you miss when copy-pasting?